# Erro "No package dkim-milter available" CentOS 5.8

Tags: linux, centos, dkim

Não consigo instalar o dkim-milter, estou usando CentOS 5.8 x64bit

> [root@server ~]# yum install dkim-milter
>       Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
>       Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
>       * base: mirror.ubiquityservers.com
>       * epel: fedora-epel.mirror.lstn.net
>       * extras: centos.den.host-engine.com
>       * rpmforge: mirror.nexcess.net
>       * updates: mirror.sanctuaryhost.com
>       Setting up Install Process
>       No package dkim-milter available.
>       Nothing to doa

Como resolver?

Comment: Conseguiu resolver seu problema?

Comment: @EduardoSeixas vc tem a solução?

Comment: tenho uma dica.

Comment: Qual tutorial você está seguindo?

Comment: Votei por deixar aberta a questão, pois apesar do problema ser na instalação, o intuito do uso é a programação, já que `dkim-milter` é uma biblioteca C, mas posso estar totalmente enganado sobre o escopo da pergunta especifica, então me perdoem qualquer engano (note que faltam 2 votos pra decidir até o momento). Sobre o dkim-milter acho que ele foi substituído pelo opendkim, portanto este pode ser o motivo de não conseguir instalar.

Comment: Também votei por deixar a questão aberta, ela está entendível, embora não esteja boa.

Answer (score 1):

## O QUE É DKIM

DKIM (DomainKeys Identified Mail) é um importante mecanismo de autenticação para ajudar a proteger ambos os receptores de e-mail e os remetentes de e-maiils forjados e phishing. O sistema DKIM (DomainKeys Identified Mail) é uma evolução do sistema DomainKeys inicialmente desenvolvido por Yahoo como um mecanismo para que um e-mail possa ser validado por um destinatário, comprovando de forma inequívoca que a sua origem é realmente a que aparece nos cabeçalhos do e-mail.

## INSTALAÇÃO

**1 - ATIVAR EPEL REPOSITÓRIO**

> # rpm -Uvh http://epel.mirror.net.in/epel/5/x86_64/epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm

**2 - TESTAR EPEL REPOSITÓRIO**

> # yum --disablerepo=* --enablerepo=epel list all

**3 - INSTALANDO DKIM-MILTER**

> % sudo yum –enablerepo=epel install -y dkim-milter

Comment: Você tem respondido várias perguntas que não são de programação. Não sei se entendeu qual são os tópicos aqui. Estas perguntas devem ser fechadas. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Entendi. Obrigado por verificar.

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/102782/como-ultilizar-um-driver-do-windows-no-linux é o mesmo caso né? Como Instalar não tem nada haver né?

Comment: Sim, votei para fechar.

Comment: Só uma nota, dkim-milter foi substituído pelo opendkim.